# Converting Apache .htaccess to Nginx Directives

Tags: nginx, url, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I've run my site on Apache for years, and since I've made the transition over to Nginx for speed preference, my htaccess rewrite rules have broken my site.

My site content is served dynamically based on the URL request - here's how my htaccess file looks for / traffic.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-\_]+)/$ index.php?first_path=$1 [QSA]
```

This will pass any directory as a first_path param to index.php.

Reading through the Nginx documentation for url restructuring, I can't seem to figure out how to write my requirements.

Any ideas will help.

Comment: You could use something like: `rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?first_path=$1 last;`

Comment: @RichardSmith, do you write it somewhere specific in the nginx.conf file between a block of some sort? or just by itself on the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with online converters like [this one](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx), which specifically to your `.htaccess` will produce:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-\_]+)/$ /index.php?first_path=$1;
}
```

Naturally, you also have to include a "handler" location for PHP processing so a more complete configuration would be:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-\_]+)/$ /index.php?first_path=$1;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/path/to/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

It's worth noting though, that the creator of NGINX himself, Igor Sysoev, is not in favor of using `rewrite` directives, [dismissing their use to old times when nested locations were not supported](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-locations-performance-impact-and-optimizations).

Nested locations, as per NGINX author allow isolating regular expression thus creating a configuration that is easier to maintain in the future (not necessarily easier to create at first though). So in this case, using nested location, the same config may look like this:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / { 

        location ~ ^/(?<dir>[a-zA-Z0-9-z\-\_]+)/$ {
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/path/to/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/index.php;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING first_path=$dir
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/path/to/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm still having a hard time wrapping my head around this. I placed this in my conf file, and replaced the required fields, but my URL rerouting is still not wokring. I read somewhere that the file needs to include ngx_http_rewrite_module, is that right? Because my file isn't showing it

Comment: NGINX config is typically made up of many files, and the standard convention is having `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com.conf` files for site-specific logic. Make sure that those are included in case you are using them (`nginx -T` to dump complete configuration). The `ngx_http_rewrite_module` does not need to be enabled, if you have installed NGINX from packages, it is enabled/included.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks so much! I got it to work fine now. I have the same htaccess URL rewrite for other directories, what do I write for another location block?